# Fast method for forward filling with function nans in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a sparse dataframe with integer values. For example we create `df` as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(10), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.loc[(0,'A')] = 6
df.loc[(3,'A')] = 8
df.loc[(4,'B')] = 2
```

and it looks like this

```
    A   B   C
0   6 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3   8 NaN NaN
4 NaN   2 NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN NaN
9 NaN NaN NaN
```

Now I want to recursively fill each nan value with the previous value -1 (if it is not nan). For example this code does the trick:

```
for j in range(len(df.index)):
    df = df.fillna(value=df.shift(1)-1, limit=1)
```

and it produces

```
   A   B   C
0  6 NaN NaN
1  5 NaN NaN
2  4 NaN NaN
3  8 NaN NaN
4  7   2 NaN
5  6   1 NaN
6  5   0 NaN
7  4  -1 NaN
8  3  -2 NaN
9  2  -3 NaN
```

The problem is that this code applied to a "real" dataframe is slow as hell, even if I have a bound on the range of `j`. Since it looks like very close to a simple `df.fillna(method='ffill')`, which is way faster, I was wondering if there is a way to speed this process up.

Thanks in advance for any answer, insight or comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a general solution but should produce the expected output in your particular case:

```
for col in df.columns:
    g = df[col].notnull().cumsum()
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(method='ffill') - df[col].groupby(g).cumcount()
```

Basically you fill forward and then subtract the number of consecutive nans after the last nonnull value.

Comment: Thanks gereleth! It works, and it is indeed much faster. Do you know whether the difference in performance comes from not passing a dataframe to the 'value' argument of fillna at each step?

Comment: I think your code does two whole-dataframe operations for every row - first `shift` and then `fillna`. That's a lot more number-crunching than necessary =).

Answer (score 0):

My comparisons on your toy problem suggest the below code is quicker than yours and the accepted answer; your mileage may vary on your actual problem.

```
for col,series in df.iteritems():
    reference = series[0]
    for idx,val in series.iteritems():
        if np.isnan(val):
            reference = reference - 1
            series[idx] = reference
        else:
            reference = val
```